# Abstract class with wrong logic

Tags: java, arrays, methods, abstract

I'm supposed to make a program that has `MotorVehicle` abstract class. `Car`, `Truck`, `Van` are kinds of `MotorVehicle`. The `setTerms()` and `displayInfo()` are the only abstract. `Car` has `String transType` and `void Car()`, `Van` has `int numPassenger` and `void Van(`), as `Truck` has `double payLoad` and `void Truck()`.

The output should be like this:

> Brand is Mazda
>
> Vehicle type is Sedan
>
> Color is Red
>
> Transmission type is Automatic
>
> Price is 840000.0
>
> Terms is 5 years to pay
>
> Brand is Isuzu
>
> Vehicle type is Truck
>
> Color is White
>
> Payload capacity is 3.5
>
> Price is 910000.0
>
> Terms is 3 years to pay
>
> Brand is Mitsubishi
>
> Vehicle type is Family Van
>
> Color is Blue
>
> Number of passenger is  8
>
> Price is 1050000.0
>
> Terms is 7 years to pay

But my program doesn't still produce this output

Here's my current codes:

```
public abstract class MotorVehicle
{
    private String vehicleType;
    private String brand;
    private String color;
    private String terms;

    public MotorVehicle(String vcl, String brn, String clr, String trm)
    {
        vehicleType = vcl;
        brand = brn;
        color = clr;
        terms = trm;
    }

    public String getVehicleType()
    {
        return vehicleType;
    }

    public String getBrand()
    {
        return brand;
    }

    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    public abstract void setTerms();

    public abstract void displayInfo();

}

//=========================================

public class Car extends MotorVehicle
{
    String transType="";
    String vehicleType;
        String brand;
    String color;
    String terms;
    int price = 0;

    public Car(String vcl, String brn, String clr, String trm)
    {
        super(vcl, brn, clr, trm);
        vehicleType = vcl;
        brand = brn;
        color = clr;
        terms = trm;
    }

    public void Car()
    {
        brand = "Mazda";
        vehicleType = "Sedan";
        color = "Red";
        transType = "Automatic";
        price = (int) (700000 + (700000*0.2));
        Double.toString(price);
        terms = "5";   
    }

    public void setTerms()
    {
         return;
    }

    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Brand is " + brand);
        System.out.println("Vehicle type is " + vehicleType);
        System.out.println("Color is " + color);
        System.out.println("Transmission type is " + transType);
        System.out.println("Price is " + price);
        System.out.println("Terms is " + terms + " years to pay");
    }

}

//=================================

public class Truck extends MotorVehicle
{
    double payLoad=0.0;
    String vehicleType;
        String brand;
    String color;
    String terms;
    int price = 0;

    public Car(String vcl, String brn, String clr, String trm)
    {
        super(vcl, brn, clr, trm);
        vehicleType = vcl;
        brand = brn;
        color = clr;
        terms = trm;
    }

    public void Truck()
    {
        brand = "Isuzu";
        vehicleType = "Truck";
        color = "White";
        payLoad = 3.5;
        Double.toString(payLoad);
        price = (int) (700000 + (700000*0.3));
        Double.toString(price);
        terms = "3";     
    }

    public void setTerms()
    {
         return;
    }

    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Brand is " + brand);
        System.out.println("Vehicle type is " + vehicleType);
        System.out.println("Color is " + color);
        System.out.println("Payload capacity is " + payLoad);
        System.out.println("Price is " + price);
        System.out.println("Terms is " + terms + " years to pay");
    }   


 }

//==========================

public class Van extends MotorVehicle
{
    int numPassenger=0;
    String vehicleType;
        String brand;
    String color;
    String terms;
    int price=0;

    public Van(String vcl, String brn, String clr, String trm)
    {
            super(vcl, brn, clr, trm);
        vehicleType = vcl;
        brand = brn;
        color = clr;
        terms = trm;
    }

    public void Van()
    {
    brand = "Mitsubishi";
    vehicleType = "Family Van";
    color = "Blue";
    numPassenger = 8;
    String.valueOf(numPassenger);
    price = (int) (700000 + (700000*0.5));
    Double.toString(price);
    terms = "7";   
}

public void setTerms()
{
     return;
}

public void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Brand is " + brand);
    System.out.println("Vehicle type is " + vehicleType);
    System.out.println("Color is " + color);
    System.out.println("Number of passenger is " + numPassenger);
    System.out.println("Price is " + price);
    System.out.println("Terms is " + terms + " years to pay");
}
```

}

```
//===================
```

And this is the main program:

```
public class MainVehicle 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BBVehicle[] vhl= new BBVehicle[3];

        int ctr=0;
        while(ctr<3)
        {
            if (ctr==0)
                vhl[ctr]=new Car();
            else if(ctr==1)
                vhl[ctr]= new Truck();
            else
                vhl[ctr]= new Van();
            vhl[ctr].displayInfo();
            ctr++;
        }
     }

}
```

I'm not sure with what's wrong with my program. help me please thanks

Comment: what output does it produce?

Comment: MainVehicle program still has syntax errors that's why I can't run it

Comment: Then fix the errors and test the code.

Comment: I don't need your opinion pcalcao. That's why I am asking for help

Comment: if you are getting compliation errors and would like help to sort them out, please specify those errors.

Comment: As I have said above, I only get compilation errors in the MainVehilcle specifically in the part of Car(), Truck(), Van()

Comment: i dont see that anywhere.  you can copy the output of the compiler and paste it to your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i)

```
public void Car()
public void Truck()
public void Van()
```

You are defining return type of Class Contructor

it should be

```
public Car()
public Truck()
public Van()
```

A constructor resembles an instance method, but it differs from a method in that it has no explicit return type, it is not implicitly inherited and it usually has different rules for scope modifiers.

ii) Define a no-argument constructor in the abstract class (From the comment)

iii)

```
    BBVehicle[] vhl= new BBVehicle[3];

    int ctr=0;
    while(ctr<3)
    {
        if (ctr==0)
            vhl[ctr]=new Car();
```

You are casting Car class to BBVehicle class. Although, both class are different. There is no relation between these two class..

Comment: And that would account for the compilation errors - calling the the super constructor from a method would not work.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of advice I would give is that you shouldn't hide your member variables from your superlcass.

In each of your child classes, you declare variables with the same name as the `private` variables that you define in your super class.  Instead, you should simply remove the duplicates from the child classes and either:

1. change the visibility of the variables in the superclass to something that makes them available to child classes (ie `protected`)
2. utilize getters to access them in your `displayInfo()` method.  To do this you would need to set a `get[VariableName]()`  per field in your superclass.

Comment: So all the declaration of the child classes should be private variables?

Comment: My piece of advice would be to access your private members via getters , even in the enclosing class itself. So something like:
System.out.println("Brand is " + brand); would become System.out.println("Brand is " + getBrand());